# Reputation tab doesn't show accepts

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, recent-activity

My [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416579/pessimopoppotamus?tab=reputation) doesn't show any activity/rep changes for today, even though my [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416579/pessimopoppotamus?tab=activity) confirms I accepeted a few answers.

[image: reputation tab]

vs.

[image: activity]

Is this a bug?

Comment: I see 4 accepts.  Look again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It takes a few minutes for a new day to show up on the reputation tab after the first few reputation events for the day.

It's just coincidence that these events were accepts.

Comment: Correct, this is just a caching issue, though it will be lowered from 10 to 5 minutes with the recent changes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes